# Integration Services error al exportar a excel

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, ssis

Estoy utilizando ***Visual Studio Community 2019***, específicamente ***Integration Services***. Con una tarea de flujo de datos obtengo los registros de una tabla de SQL Server usando ***Origen de OLE DB***, hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es cuando quiero pasar esos datos a un ***Destino de Excel***, ya que obtengo el siguiente error:

> Error en Tarea Flujo de datos [Destino de Excel [31]]: Column "ID" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

La vista previa muestra los registros en el ***Origen de OLE DB***, asi que asumo que el error no surge de la extracción de datos:
[image: resultset_oledb]

El ***Destino de Excel*** tiene la configuración por defecto y aun cuando entiendo que el error se debe alguna clase de conversión de tipo de dato, no tengo idea de donde cambiar el tipo de dato, ni a qué tipo debo cambiarlo, el ID originalmente en la tabla de SQL Server es `varchar(7)`:

[image: destino_excel]

Agradeceria cualquier orientacion acerca de que puede estar causando el error y como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente.

Esta es la conversión que intentas generar, y la que genera error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busca en tus herramientas un Data Conversion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Insertarla entre tu source y tu Excel destino.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entra a las propiedades de tu conversión, selecciona los registros que son de varchar, y por default te los dará en un tipo de Datos "string [DT_STR]", cámbialos a un "Unicode string[DT_WSRT]".
Únicamente sera necesario realizar eso con los campos de varchar , string.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu excel destino cambia el origen para esas columnas, en las asignaciones, Las columnas nuevas te aparecerán como "Copia de "

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciono, muchas gracias.